why title and axis labels doesn't show in python, Matplotlib, code below?
I have the following code , but for some reason it does not show title and labels. Can anyone help me? I also use VScode
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    x = np.arange(0, 100)
    y = x*2

   fig = plt.figure()
   axes = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
   axes.plot(x, y)
   axes.set_xlabel('X')  # ?
   axes.set_ylabel('y')
   axes.set_title('title')
   plt.show()`

I expect to see titles and lables when I run the code, but it's just the graph.

Depending on your environment, fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1]) will add a subplot of which the "axes" (the rectangle formed by x and y axis, and top and right) will fill the complete figure.  Try ax = plt.subplot() (note the command ends with t) instead. Or, highly recommended, create the figure and subplot(s) in one go: fig, ax = plt.subplots() (note the command ends with s), removing fig = plt.figure().

Thanks for your reply, I tried that, but nothing has changed it still shows only a line without title and axis labels.

So, you didn't remove axes = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])?

Exactly! now it works thanks a lot.
